# Irreducible bivariate complex polynomial whose zero-locus contains two given points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, affine-varieties

Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbf{C}^2$ be distinct pairs of complex numbers. Is there an irreducible polynomial $f\in\mathbf{C}[x,y]$ vanishing at $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: I just edited the message: I meant that $\alpha$ is a pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. For instance, $f(x,y)=(\beta_1-\alpha_1)(y-\alpha_2)-(\beta_2-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_1)$

Comment: Thank you. I actually had in mind a generalization of my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614359/do-closed-points-of-a-variety-lie-in-a-codimension-1-subvariety