# Do closed points of a variety lie in a codimension $1$ subvariety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a variety over a field $k$ (here, varieties are smooth, geometrically connected) and $p,q$ two closed points of $X$. Assume that $X$ is of dimension at least $2$.

Is there an irreducible closed subset of codimension $1$ of $X$ containing both $p$ and $q$?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you meant that these are finite type over $k$. Here is a lovely argument (at least when $k$ is algebraically closed) due to C. P. Ramanujam (and you can read it in his collected works).

First, (not so important), you can take the projective closure of $X$ (smoothness is irrelevant) and thus assume $X$ is projective. Then blow up $p,q$ to get $Y\to X$. $Y$ is projective and so a general hyperplane section $Z$ is irreducible by Bertini's theorem. Since the exceptional divisors meet $Z$ (hyperplane sections meet all positive dimensional subvarieites), the image of $Z$ is an irreducible divisor passing through $p,q$.

Comment: +1: I really like this proof of Ramanujam when the base field is algebraically closed (of characteristic zero)! Just to make sure: you're also assuming that $X$ is quasiprojective, don't you?

Comment: @Gaussian I am assuming quasi-projective, but I don't think characteristic zero is really necessary.

Comment: sure, you're right. Actually, I am interested in non quasi-projective varieties, so feel free to share any thought!